# How can I access a linux character device with D?

Tags: linux-device-driver, d

I would like to turn a led (character device) of an embedded linux board (BeagleBone Black) on and off with a script written in D.

Via the command line a led can be turned on and off (e.g. for led "USER LEDS D2 0") with:

```
cd /sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0
echo none > trigger
echo 1 > brightness
echo 0 > brightness
```

(`echo none > trigger` disables the default "heartbeat" flashing)

In the [D Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/d-cookbook) on page 93 I found info about how to make linux system calls via the C interface like follows:

```
void main(){
   import core.sys.posix.unistd;  // analogous to #include <unistd.h>
   string hello = "Hello, world!";
   write(1 /*stdout file descriptor*/, hello.ptr, hello.length);
}
```

Is that a suitable way to access a character device or are there better alternatives?

Comment: BTW: Using std.process like described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876553/how-to-make-a-system-call-and-read-the-stdout-in-d did also not work for me...

Comment: Both LDC and DMD compile this snippet fine for me (LDC 1.3.0 and DMD 2.075.0). What sort of errors do you get?

Comment: with dmd I get `hello.d(3): Error: unexpected ( in declarator
hello.d(3): Error: basic type expected, not 1
hello.d(3): Error: found '1' when expecting ')'
hello.d(3): Error: no identifier for declarator write(_error_)
hello.d(3): Error: semicolon expected following function declaration
hello.d(3): Error: declaration expected, not ','`

Comment: Is the code posted exactly the same as the one you compile? It misses semicolon on the `string hello = ...` line.

Comment: No, it does not lack a semicolon. It is exactly like above...

Comment: you are right, the semicolon was missing in the code snipped above. However I still get the same compilation errors when I compile with copy&pasted from above.

Comment: Maybe move this to the chat? The discussion is getting pretty long.

Comment: It's probably a very dumb question, but do you have a `main` wrapper around this? Removing it gave me exactly the errors you get.

Comment: Argh, no. You are right. (Humans should not multitask too much...) I somehow commented the main AND the closing } out. Works perfectly fine.

Comment: Always glad to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unistd` calls are indeed the correct way to do it. A character device in Linux is a special kind of file and is accessed the same way: you `open` it by path, then `read` or `write` to it, and `close` it when finished.

Note that `open` is actually inside `core.sys.posix.fcntl`, while `read` is in `core.sys.posix.unistd`.

You could also use `std.file.write()` from the D standard library to be a bit shorter. There's also `chdir` in there. So your shell example would literally become:

```
import std.file;
chdir("/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0");
std.file.write("trigger", "none"); // write "filename", "data string"
std.file.write("brightness", "1");
std.file.write("brightness", "0");
```

You don't strictly have to use `std.file.write` as the full name with the import, I just like to since `write` is such a common word it clears up which one we mean.

Anyway, this function just wraps up the unistd calls for you: it opens, writes the string, and closes all in one (just like the shell echo!).

One small difference is shell `echo` sticks a `\n` at the end of the string. I didn't do that here. If the code doesn't work, try "1\n" and such instead, maybe the device requires that. But I doubt it.

But the `std.file.write` vs the `core.sys.posix.unistd.write` aren't that much different. The former is more convenient, the latter gives more precise control over it.